# Advice on implementing my own console as an XPCOM

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I want to use my own console for my extension, where I would be printing out various debug info. I thought I would do that by doing

`window.open("chrome://myextension/content/console.xul"..`

and then printing into textboxes of that window. Do you already see something wrong here? =)

Now I have a small problem, window.open returns immediately and if I then go ahead and immediately use myconsole.log("boo") function, then the content in that newly opened window is not loaded yet and I will get errors. This means that I have to wait for the console to finish loading before I can print to it. What would be the right way of doing it? I could use nsITimer or thread.sleep inside of the log method to keep checking if it's loaded already, but I don't like this. I also don't know how I could correctly use window.onload event, because the only way I see is smth like window.onload = function() { all of my extension code.. } which I don't like either.

I want it to be used anytime anywhere somehow like this

```
console = Cc["@myconsole;1"].getService().wrappedJSObject;
console.log("foo");
```

Any advice? Thanks for the patience =)

Comment: You could maintain a list of items to log, and call your log() function in a try block on a timer until it succeeds, then flush the list.

Answer (score 2):

I would have implemented it first as a backend logging module:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules

And then write a custom chrome window which interacts with it (gets all logs, clear logs, subscribes to get new log events)

To save yourself coding time see also [console2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1815/) and (the least known) [firebug tracing console](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/tracing-console-for-firebug/):